# Adding constraint on column if value provided

Tags: postgresql, validation, constraints

I have created function to check if email is exists in users table then it allow in other table row entry. But It is mandatory so either correct email or null is allowed. But I am not sure how can I modify this constraint to perform this. My constraint function is here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_email_allowed(text)
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = $1);
$func$
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;  -- not actually IMMUTABLE
```

Now I have added this constraint to my table accounts

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD CONSTRAINT email_allowed
CHECK (email_allowed(email)) NOT VALID;
```

This is working fine but if I provide empty field for email field in account, it throws error. but I want to make sure either `null` or email for users table accepted. I can't setup relationship because it is very different relations here it is just for example I am using user/account.

Another way could be following

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD CONSTRAINT email_allowed 
FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES users(email);
```

But it has also same issue I can't use null in column. I created relations as mentioned. Here is structure of my tables.

Table: accounts

```
id  account_name  assignee
1   name          email@example.com
2   name          null
```

Table: users

```
id  name  email 
1   someone  email@example.com
```

I want to sure in account table email either be null or have only value from user email
I want to keep in

Comment: Don't do this a a `CHECK` constraint as you introduced an dependency via the function to another table and this dependency is not tracked. This will cause problems when doing a dump/restore. Use a trigger on the table instead.

Comment: As to why it does not work `...WHERE email = $1` is going to return `NULL` when `$1` is `NULL`. You could do: ``...WHERE email = $1 OR $1 IS NULL`

Comment: So what is solution? to add such validation as some one said with reference but that is not working and that fellow also deleted answer.

Comment: As I said in my original comment use a [Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). I thought you said you could not setup a relationship because the relations where too different? Show the table definitions for the tables.

Comment: Of course you can use a NULL value in a column defined as a foreign key. Defining a foreign key is the most efficient and robust way to deal with this. If your situation is different than the one you have presented in the question, then you should change your question and show us the **real** tables

Comment: Unless of course you have defined `email` as `NOT NULL`:)

Comment: I added strucutre. I have presented here two ways, one with relationship, another with function. @AdrianKlaver which trigger are you talking about?

Comment: That is an incomplete structure.  You need to show the complete table definition including data types, constraints/indexes(Primary key, Unique, Not Null,etc). This can be obtained in `psql` by doing `\d accounts` and `\d users`.  You will have to create the trigger using  a modified version of your function. See the link I sent for the create trigger portion and [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) for the function portion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add relationship, so the column is nullable then it will accept nulls.

But if any eamil is provided then following line will make sure it is present in user -> email column

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD CONSTRAINT FK_users_email FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES users(email);
```

All comments were valid I have error as I have run one of migration previous so it was doing effect.